# Помогите исправить ошибку shutil

Tags: python, файлы, ос, shutil

Делаю функцию для распаковки архива (в папке с архивом создаётся папка в которой все файлы):

```
def unpack_archives(archive_path):
    archive_path = Path(archive_path + '/archive')
    for archive in archive_path.rglob("*"):
        try:
            shutil.unpack_archive(archive, archive_path)
        except BaseException:
            continue
```

Вылазит ошибка, если файл уже был распакован, то есть там файл уже создан. Как это убрать? Какую ошибку вписать в try. Если у меня два архива в папке и один уже был распакован, то я не смогу из-за ошибки распаковать второй архив. Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\Test_Project\Test.py", line 125, in <module>
    sort_files(files_paths, groups_of_files)
  File "C:\Projects\Test_Project\Test.py", line 45, in sort_files
    shutil.move(file_path, path_folder_for_sort + '/' + name_group)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 822, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/Projects/Example/documents\kek.txt' already exists
```

Comment: Не совсем ответ на вопрос, но почему бы в archive_path не делать путь с именами архивов? Что-то вроде `archive_path + '/' + archive_name`?

Comment: Как мне имя архива достать?

Comment: оно у вас в переменной `archive`

Comment: Ага, понял. Только как мне archive использовать до цикла for?
archive_path = Path(archive_path + '/' + archive)
    for archive in archive_path.rglob("*"):
        shutil.unpack_archive(archive, archive_path)

Comment: И в таком случае будет ошибка:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'
Нельзя к объекту Path добавлять строку

Comment: чтобы ошибки исключить, лучше, конечно, соединять пути через [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Если делать пути с именами архивов, то строчка с путём должна быть не до цикла, а в цикле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы разгрузить ветку комментариев, предложу код в ответе. Распаковываем каждый архив в отдельную папку с его названием.

```python
import os

def unpack_archives(archive_path):
    for archive in archive_path.rglob("*"):
        shutil.unpack_archive(archive, os.path.join(archive_path, archive))
```

Если неправильно отработает, пиши.

Предлагаю не заморачиваться с пропуском ошибки, т.к. если в двух архивах есть папка, допустим, `/images`, то при варианте с обработкой ошибок данная папка запишется только из одного архива, а вторая будет игнорирована, что, вероятно, не очень бы хотелось.

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rglob'

Comment: @Pain значит путь неправильный